# Listing all apps that updated at once

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, application-autoupdate

When multiple apps update in one batch they trigger a single system notification saying X apps updated and listing about two of them. Then it takes one to Google Play app where "recent" updates are listed - but this list includes multiple last update batches so even more than X apps are listed. Is there a way i can see the real X app names that updated in the  very last batch only?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it via the play store, but there are other ways to do it.

You can use something like [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (if rooted) to display the list of apps **ordered by last update date**. This will show you the order in which all apps were last updated, as well as the date of the update. To me this a lot more useful than the recently updated list in the play store.

It's not a perfect solution, but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this, but it must be done before applying latest batch of updates, so maybe it will not be as practical as one might expect, as you'll find out below:

- Go to the app drawer and drag up the **Play Store** icon, to **App info**.
- Tap the button **Clear data** and confirm
- Next time you start Play Store app, it will greet you asking you to accept the TOS again, do it.
- Now the list of recently updated apps will be merged with earlier ones, and next update batch, when done, will show on top of the list.

To be honest, I don't recommend you this procedure because of potential collateral effects derived from clearing app data too frequently. I'm posting this answer only for informative purposes, but I'd rather go with the [answer given by @Krampus](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59853/12677)